# Unable to link with the right version of libldap

Tags: 22.04, ldap

I have a build machine where I have installed `libldap-dev` and the
target host, I only have `libldap`. The versions are same

Build:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libldap 
ii  libldap-2.5-0:amd64   2.5.16+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1  amd64  OpenLDAP libraries
ii  libldap-common        2.5.16+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1  all    OpenLDAP common files for libraries
ii  libldap-dev:amd64     2.5.16+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1  amd64  OpenLDAP development libraries
```

Target:

```
[root@jammy-88: bin]# dpkg -l | grep libldap
ii  libldap-2.5-0:amd64  2.5.16+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1  amd64  OpenLDAP libraries 
ii  libldap-common       2.5.16+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1  all    OpenLDAP common files for libraries
```

I don't know where the build is picking up this reference to a `2.4` version of `libldap`.
When I try installing my binaries on the target, I see this unresolved reference:

```
[root@jammy-88: bin]# ldd my-bin | grep ldap 
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => not found
```

I don't even have that library on my build host:

```
root@ubuntu-jammy-build:~# find / -name libldap_r-2.4.so.2
root@ubuntu-jammy-build:~#
```

I have tried multiple clean rebuilds, also tried `apt-get update` to install
the latest+same `libldap` package - 2.5
:-/

How can I ensure that my binary links to `libldap-2.5-0` ...
Do I have to change some package config ?

Comment: What does `ldd my-bin` report on the build machine?

Comment: @muru on my build machine it does not show a reference to `libldap` at all ! as in `ldd my-bin | grep libldap` does not show anything

Comment: @Terrance its mostly something to do with the host/libs as I am able to build and get the same code to work on an older (Ubuntu Bionic) without any issues

Comment: Then you might want to try `lddtree` instead from the `pax-utils` package (on both systems)

Comment: ok, I installed and tried now, even `lddtree` is not showing any reference to `libldap` on the build host!

Comment: @muru  But `lddtree` on my target shows (based on indent) under `libcurl`! so maybe something off with that! I will explore in that direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Terrance yea, I had it too, but then I remove snap and all its related packages and that got removed (`snap remove --purge lxd` et al)

Comment: I wonder if it could be something "stale" in the ld.so cache on the target machine? what do you get if you run (as an unprivileged user) `ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep libldap`?

Comment: There was a stale version of custom built libcurl, which I had to remove!

Comment: Thanks for all your help!